# Firebase and Google Cloud projects consolidation

Tags: firebase, migration, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database

I've opened a Google cloud project with multiple GCE, SQL and storage instances, along with an android app linked to it, about a year ago. In addition I've had 2 Firebase projects, one for production and one for dev environments, that were of course not linked to my Cloud project.

Now that the new Firebase is here, I would like to link all these accounts.

I have imported my Cloud project to the Firebase console, but it has its own Firebase DB, I'm not able to link it to my actual Firebase DBs (projects)... I can see my App analytics and cloud messaging but not my Firebase data, as the two Firebase projects are still considered as other projects.

How do I link or consolidate all these accounts together, Cloud and Firebases? And if not all, what about only the production one into my Cloud project?

This is how my Firebase dashboard looks right now:

[image: s]

Answer (score 1):

You can import your firebase.com app into a new Firebase project and you can separately import your Google project into a Firebase project. However, we do not support merging these 2 imported projects.

If you want to use Firebase Auth or Firebase Invites in your Firebase project and if you have your OAuth Client registered with another Google project, you can add the OAuth client ID of your Google project into your Firebase project.

Comment: This is a major problem since I'm interested in most of the new Firebase functionalities... The merging of the production Firebase and The Google Cloud project is needed for proper Analytics, Crash reporting and Cloud Storage integration. If this kind of merger is not possible, can I at least rename the DB of my Cloud DB that was created when  I imported the project to Firebase? It will save me a lot of updates for currently active clients...

Comment: Also, is it possible to change the default Cloud Storage bucket that is assigned to the new Firebase project that was opened for me when I imported my Cloud project to Firebase? I need to change it to an existing one that's being used in other parts of my system, updating them will be quite a hassle. Also the location and area that was assigned to the Firebase bucket is not optimal for me

Comment: See sriram's comment above on using Analytics, Crash reporting etc.

Answer (score 1):

@Aralizer, you should be able to use Analytics, Crash reporting etc on the project you import from firebase.com. This Firebase project can co-exist with your previous Google Cloud project for GCE, Cloud SQL etc. It seems like you may have registered an OAuth Client in the Cloud project that you want to reuse in the Firebase project. This is possible by whitelisting the Cloud project's OAuth client ID in the Firebase project. Check this helpcenter article for more details on how to do this: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008

Comment: This does not allow old Google Cloud projects that have OAuth integrated for Google Play Game Services to share the SHA1 hash with Firebase that is required for Firebase to access IAP information from the Google Play store. We're stuck trying to figure out how to fix that issue without pulling our apps off of the Google Play store during a transition.